# Mongodb $lookup/populate and summarize

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to join two schema and summarize the total price.
This is the schema:

```
const Product = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  price: Number
})

const Order = new mongoose.Schema({
  fullname: { type: String, required: true },
  address: { type: String, required: true },
  products: [
    {
      product: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product',
      },
      quantity: Number,
    },
  ],
})
```

I want to create aggregation to get orders with total price.so it could be like:

```
[
  {
    fullname: 'jhon doe',
    address: 'NY 1030',
    products: [
      {
        product: {
          name: 'Piano',
          price: 50
        },
        quantity: 10,
      },
    ],
    price: 500
  }
]
```

I try to use aggregation framework without any success, any idea?

Comment: You might as well just use relational database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

As the question needs the price to be calculated by sum of the multiplication of quantity and product price, It can be done with below code:

```js
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
  { $unwind: { path: '$products' } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'products',
      localField: 'products.product',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'p',
    },
  },
  { $unwind: { path: '$p' } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      price: { $sum: { $multiply: ['$p.price', '$products.quantity'] } },
      fullname: { $first: '$fullname' },
      address: { $first: '$address' },
      products: { $push: { product: '$p', quantity: '$products.quantity' } },
    },
  },
])
```

**----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

You can use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) in aggregation as below:

```js
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'products',
      localField: 'products.product',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'p',
    },
  },
  { $unwind: { path: '$p' } },
  {
    $project: {
      fullname: 1,
      address: 1,
      products: {
        product: '$p',
        quantity: 1,
      },
      price: 1,
    },
  },
])
```

Comment: thanks for response but I want "price" to be calculation of all products ... products.quantity * products.product.price

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that! I updated the response based on what you needed!

Comment: your'e the best! question... is there an option to merge all another properties without specific one by one ? (such as fullname, address...) because if I want to add more properties i have to change this query

Comment: Yeah, you can do it with a trick: 
{$group : 
         {_id: "$_id",
          price:{$sum: { $multiply: [ "$p.price", "$products.quantity" ] }},
          root: { $first: '$$ROOT' },
     }},
     { $project:{
         price: 1,
         root: "$root",
         products: {
            product: '$root.p',
            quantity: '$root.products.quantity',
          }
         }
         },
     {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [{ price: '$price' },'$root',{ products: '$products' }] }
    }},
    { $project:{
        p:0
        }
        }

Comment: it works but the products array isn't populated. sorry for that I ask you to help me with specific query :( by the way... is there any resource can I learn about that, the mongo docs quite complex

Comment: You should keep the parts before `$group` section (keep lookup and unwinds) in the answer and replace the group parts and parts after that with the above comment ;)

Comment: Actually the best way to learn is to read the mongo docs itself, and also search small logical pieces in stack overflow.